# Tychonoff Topology and Closure Operator.

Tags: general-topology

After the 2.3.6 corollary in Engelking's *General Topology*, there is an observation alerting the reader that the [Tychonoff Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) cannot be generated by the [closure operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator) defined by 
$$\overline{\prod_{s\in S} A_{s}} = \prod_{s\in S}\overline{A}_{s},$$

for not all subset $B$ of the space $\prod_{s\in S} X_s$ can be represented in the form $\prod_{s\in S} B_s$, such that, for all $s\in S$, $B_s\subseteq X_s$.

But, if ${p}_{s}: \prod_{s\in S} X_s \to X_s$ are the projections and given $B\subseteq \prod_{s\in S} X_s$, it is not true that $B = \prod_{s\in S} {p}_{s}[B]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, consider the diagonal $D = \{(x,x): x \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.
Here $\pi_1[D] = \pi_2[D] = \mathbb{R}$ and $D \neq \mathbb{R}^2$.
$D$ is an example of a (closed) set that we cannot write as the product of two closed sets in the factors.

Comment: This is a great example to keep in mind to avoid this and other common errors.